# Right way to store which user is connected in my AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to keep in my app which user is connected. I'm really not sure if I'm doing this correctly. So here is how I plane to do it:

First I use my Slim API to check if the username and password are correct and if has access privilege.

If it returned the username and his privilege level, I  will store them in a cookie and use those two information in the app.

The problem is that I'm afraid that if I store the username in a cookie, someone could try to change the cookie and put an other username instead.

Is it alright to only use the username for my requests to the DB as soon as the user is connected (like get all item of a user using the name of the user), or should I use a more secured and efficient way, if there is one?

P.S: I'm not asking how to have my site remember the user when he go back to the site. I'm asking how I should remember the username and other information while my user is still on my site in a secured way.

Comment: what about localStorage?

Comment: localStorage would be secured? Because if someone is capable of changing the username, that's when it's dangerous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a long random number password  and store that in a cookie. This random number is essentially just another unique password for this user. So, on the server side, you only store a properly salted hash of this random number. Think of this like a Hash key for that user stored in DB, and you use this HASH  key to decrypt the long ramdom password.

Comment: I don't see how this help me or answer the question. I want to be able to keed the informations from my DB somewhere safe where absolutly no one would be able to access it accept me for when I want to access data that concerne the current user. I don't want to need to ask to the user to give is password every time.

Comment: Cookie or localStorage or anything...there is always a way to temper them, unless you encrypt information and verify it when user comes back to site.

Comment: I get what you mean, I just don't understand you answer. COuld you make it more simple to understand?

Comment: follow steps here: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Comment: I'm not asking how to have my site remember the user when he go back to the site. I'm asking how I should remember the username and other information while my user is still on my site in a secured way.

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt these informations in the cookie, so nobody can steal these ones. Each time a user is trying to launch your application check if the credentials in the cookie are still correct (Is this username in your databse ? Is the accreditation level correct for this user ?). So you know if these informations have been changed. If they aren't correct you invite the user to login again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by uncrypt

Comment: It's a misspelling. I wanted to say encrypt with md5 or SHA1.

Comment: But, he could change the information after having launch the app